# How does learning spells work when multiclassing out of Warlock?

Tags: dnd-5e, warlock, spellcasting, multi-classing, bard

I am trying to prepare a Warlock/Bard multiclass in DnD 5e (starting at Warlock and multiclassing into Bard) and am a bit tied up on the specifics of learning Bard spells.

As a 6th level Warlock taking his first level into Bard, I have two 3rd-level slots as part of my Pact Magic feature, and will gain two 1st-level slots from the Bard's Spellcasting feature. According to the PHB under "Spells Known of 1st Level and Higher,"

> You know four 1st-level spells of your choice from the bard spell list. The Spells Known column of the Bard table shows when you learn more bard spells of your choice. Each of these spells must be of a level for which you have spell slots, as shown on the table.

This leads into 2 questions:

1. Is the "four 1st-level spells" bit assuming I am a 1st-level character who would only have access to 1st-level spell slots, or written specifically to apply to a character with only 1 level into Bard (and therefore only having 1st-level bard spell slots)? That is, am I locked into choosing 1st-level spells despite having 3rd-level (Pact Magic) spell slots available?
2. Similarly, as I level up in the Bard class, am I able to learn 2nd- or 3rd-level Bard spells right away since I would be able to cast them using my slots from Pact Magic, or am I limited to the levels of my Bard spell slots only?

Comment: Answering your first question are these: "[If I multiclass into 2 or more spellcasting classes, how do I determine my known/prepared spells?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/151000)" and "[How does learning spells work when leveling a multiclass character?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/142715)" And answering the second are those as well as this: "[Can you cast a 9th level spell if your multiclass spell slots have 9th level spell slots?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/68604)"